# React afeta o SEO?

Tags: react, seo, single-page-application

Como o HTML é gerado via JavaScript e até que a página seja carregada não há nela HTML útil, o SEO pode ser afetado se eu fizer uma aplicação web 100% em React – uma chamada *single page application*?

Ademais, quando usamos dados vindos de uma API externa e montamos o HTML com base neles, o mecanismo de busca consegue esperar o carregamento dessas APIs?

Comment: Boa leitura https://goomore.com/blog/seo-vs-react-crawlers-mais-inteligentes/

Comment: Se a resposta e links e opiniões por ai estivessem corretas não teria surgido o SSR (Server Side Rendering) que apesar das propagandas boca a boca (texto a texto, blog a blog, YT a YT) falando bem ainda sim não dizem que é uma coisa criada para resolver um problema que os proprios devs criaram, ou seja criam o problema ai tem que criar algo extra para resolver o problema e amarrar os 2 juntos. As pessoas não entendem o básico de HTTP, começam a trabalhar com WEB, criam coisas ruins e remendos (como SSR). Sim React, Angular e cia podem afetar o SEO se não sabe o mínimo (a maioria não sabe).

Comment: TUDO pode afetar o SEO, pois a inteligência de máquina trabalha na direção oposta aos SEOs que querem simplesmente ranking. Veja quanto o Google tem em suas politicas sobre ranking de paginas, justamente usando tempos de resposta da primeira carga do site. Neste ponto REACT não é a melhor opção, porém, os motores atuais são capazes de receber todo o conteúdo e esperar a resposta do DOM para ler a página, e usar os conteúdos dinamicamentegerados, desde que acessiveis pelo browser.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar do Google informar que já consegue rastrear sites *Single Page Application* (SPA), não temos relatos se a velocidade de indexação na SERP é a mesma quando entregamos o **HTML** com o conteúdo já disponivel.

### Qual a desvantagem do SPA para o SSR?

> A desvantagem do SPA é que ele fornece inicialmente um documento HTML
> vazio, que força um rastreador a executar Javascript antes de ver
> qualquer conteúdo. O SSR sai na frente, pois todo o conteúdo
> importante está disponível no primeiro HTML.

### Experimentos?

Esse [blog](https://spa-blog.kroghweb.no/seo-in-2020-ssr-vs-spa) criou um experimento utilizando o **Next.JS** para **SSR** para gerar a mesma versão do site com o conteúdo pré-renderizado.

As dúvidas em busca de uma resposta eram:

- Ambos os sites serão indexados?
- Todas as subpáginas serão indexadas?
- Qual metodologia terá melhor desempenho *?

De acordo com o [projeto testado](https://github.com/hakonkrogh/seo-spa-vs-ssr) (open-source) o teste ocorreu em Março de 2020.

Entenda que já faz algum tempo que ocorreu o teste e o resultado pode ser diferente atualmente, é bem possível que o Google e outros motores de busca já consigam lidar de uma melhor maneira durante sua análise.

Comment: SSR, a solução criada pelas mesmas pessoas que criaram os problemas. Porque nesse mundo "moderno" o que importa é complicar para **parecer** melhor, parecer mais eficiente, custar mais caro, mesmo que não seja caro o salário do DEV e sim os custos com servidor que aumentam significativamente. Mesmo que as maneiras antigas fossem muito bem feitas e que funcionavam até melhor (claro que dependia apenas do conhecimento) o que vale hoje é "moderno". O problema é gente despreparada e que queriam(querem) misturar Desktop com Web, que entraram na área. Hoje é exigido foguetes para viagens municipais.

Comment: Só pra constar, não é uma critica a resposta e nem a sua pessoa. São só algumas coisas que acho que devem ser "pontuadas". A maioria desses conceitos, ideias, libs, frameworks, são exageros que nascem e as pessoas adotam achando que encontraram o santo graal e propagam tudo isso como sendo verdades absolutas.

Comment: Me sinto na obrigação de ressaltar que o termo SSR do jeito que é usado hoje, é sinal de remendo e imaturidade da atual "geração web". Toda página estática já é "renderizada no server" por natureza, assim como toda página PHP, ASP, ou de qualquer linguagem que roda no servidor. O problema nasceu com excesso de JS aonde não precisava, sem visão de futuro, aí quando deu caca, remendaram. (troquei ASP por PHP em 1999 e nunca tive margem para problema de indexação, com zero esforço. Foi só não inventar moda). Solução real é não usar complexidade onde não precisa. PS: não é critica à resposta hein!

Answer (score -1):

Foi feita uma [publicação](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) explicando isso, que diz que se você não  impedir que o Googlebot rastreie seus arquivos JavaScript ou CSS, ele vai conseguir renderizar e entender suas páginas da web como navegadores modernos.
Então se você deixar esses arquivos acessíveis para o Googlebot sua aplicação não será afetada.
 
Mas lembrando que é essencial seguir todas as boas práticas para SEO, como as metas de cada página, sitemap e afins...

Answer (score -3):

Uma aplicação em react afeta demais o SEO, para isso que o [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs)(Server Side Rendering) um framework do react para renderizar todo html e css no back-end.

Answer (score -8):

O básico sobre HTTP é que ele é um protocolo para troca de textos, e links como nós(nodes). O HTTP funciona como um protocolo de requisição-resposta no modelo computacional cliente-servidor, partindo deste pressuposto, sim, usar algo renderizado totalmente no cliente fere a primeira diretriz que é a resposta a requisição.
A versão HTTP/1.0 foi desenvolvida entre 1992 e 1996 para suprir a necessidade de transferir não apenas texto. Com essa versão, o protocolo passou a transferir mensagens do tipo MIME44 (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extension) e foram implementados novos métodos de requisição, fururamente, uma versão do protocolo descrito na RFC 2616,foi desenvolvido um conjunto de implementações adicionais como o uso de conexões persistentes; o uso de servidores proxy; novos métodos de requisições; entre outros. Afirma-se que o HTTP também é usado como um protocolo genérico para comunicação entre os agentes de utilizadores e proxies/gateways com outros protocolos, como o SMTP, NNTP, FTP, Gopher, e WAIS, permitindo o acesso a recursos disponíveis em aplicações diversas.

Uma sessão HTTP é uma sequência de transações de rede de requisição-resposta. Um cliente HTTP inicia uma requisição estabelecendo uma conexão Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) para uma porta particular de um servidor (normalmente a porta 80. Veja Lista de portas dos protocolos TCP e UDP). Um servidor HTTP ouvindo naquela porta espera por uma mensagem de requisição de cliente. Recebendo a requisição, o servidor retorna uma linha de estado, como "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", e uma mensagem particular própria. O corpo desta mensagem normalmente é o recurso solicitado, apesar de uma mensagem de erro ou outra informação também poder ser retornada.

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol`

Para quem precisar de mais detalhes, e o caminho que o protocolo vem sendo direcionado, este link da WIKIPEDIA pode esclarecer muito sobre a comunicação HTTP e as vantagens dele.....

Comment: essa resposta não tem nada a ver com a pergunta em sí